# Gitlab CI Cannot Pull From Container Registery

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have some images on Gitlab's container registry. I can view them on the registry page, and the urls look the same as I'm using in my gitlab-ci.yml. I'm also using (what I thought was) an identical setup in another Gitlab account/project and it works well.

However on this project I am getting the error

```
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/infra/build-images/gcloud-node ...
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/infra/build-images/gcloud-node, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (manager.go:237:0s)
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/infra/build-images/gcloud-node" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/infra/build-images/gcloud-node, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (manager.go:237:0s)
```

I have added a docker login command suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530806) to both a top-level before_script, and the before_script on to the stanza of the stage that uses the image from the registry. To facilitate this, I also added a deploy token at the top-level group named `gitlab-deploy-token` with all available permissions checked and get the same error. However one thing to note here is that even before attempting the `docker login ...` I added a line like

```
  - echo "GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN_DEBUG $CI_DEPLOY_USER $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY"
```

and don't see the output printed at all. This is true for the top-level before_script, and also the one in the stage that uses the image.

I've used the registry URL from the error output and locally logged in with `docker login registry.gitlab.com/my-repo`

however when trying to do `docker pull registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/infra/build-images/gcloud-node` I get:

```
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I'm not sure if that's relevant or a red herring, but just some additional information. When I `docker login` locally I used a personal access token that I gave every scope available. This is also how I constructed my git origin URL in both the project that published the images, and the one that's trying to use them, ie:

```
git remote set-url origin https://$TOKEN_NAME:$TOKEN_VALUE@gitlab.com/my-repo/top-level-project-that-uses-the-image.git
```

In the other Gitlab account/project that uses this setup, I don't have a deploy token or a docker config file like I've seen suggested in a couple places, it just seems to work, so I think I'm just missing some bit of setup.

For reference here is what I think is the relevant yaml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  TF_STATE_NAME: default
  TF_CACHE_KEY: default
  IMAGE_SUFFIX: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  GCP_IMAGE_TAG: gcr.io/$GCP_INFRA_PROJECT_ID/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$IMAGE_SUFFIX
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

build:docker:
  stage: build
  image: registry.gitlab.com/my-repo/infra/build-images/gcloud-node
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    GCR_SA_KEY:
  services:
    - docker:19.03.11-dind
  before_script:
    - echo "GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN $CI_DEPLOY_USER $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY"
    - docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet us-docker.pkg.dev
    - cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin  https://gcr.io
```

#### How can I get gitlab/docker to pull an image from its own container registry?

Update:

I think this visualization of my project structure might be helpful:

```
-  my-project
  -  infra
    -  build-images
      -  gcloud-node
      - ️ Container Registry (from side menu)
        -  gcloud-node
          - 4c353f7c
          - latest
  -  sites
    -  site
      -  gcloud-node
- ️ Container Registry (from side menu)
  -  gcloud-node
    - 4c353f7c
    - latest
```

I noticed when I was verifying this structure that `infra/build-images` and the top-level group `my-project` have "Container Registry" (in the left-side drawer menu), while `sites/site` does not. However both registries have the same SHA tags and both have the same URLs my-project/infra/build-images/gcloud-node for that image.

Comment: The `before_script` and `script` lines run inside the container, so if it can't be pulled, then they won't execute, because the pull happens first.